# How to groupby all the objects starts with of a dataframe in column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Have a dataframe where I need to group by and sum all the data

I have used regex function to find and group all the particular group of data starts with respective countries.

Suppose I have a dataset

```
Hierarchy   Cost   Type    Region
A   10  I   X
A   10  I   Y
A   10  J   X
A   10  J   Y
A/B 10  I   X
A/B 10  I   Y
A/B 10  J   X
A/B 10  J   Y
A/B/C   10  I   X
A/B/C   10  I   Y
A/B/C   10  J   X
A/B/C   10  J   Y
A/B/C   10  K   X
A/B/C   10  K   Y
```

Expected Output :

```
Hierarchy   Cost   Type    Region
A   30  I   X
A   30  I   Y
A   30  J   X
A   30  J   Y
A   10  K   X
A   10  K   Y
A/B 20  I   X
A/B 20  I   Y
A/B 20  J   X
A/B 20  J   Y
A/B 10  K   X
A/B 10  K   Y
A/B/C   10  I   X
A/B/C   10  I   Y
A/B/C   10  J   X
A/B/C   10  J   Y
A/B/C   10  K   X
A/B/C   10  K   Y
```

Rules for grouping:
The only thing tricky is the "Hierarchy", I'd like to get the cost in the output is the sum of itself and all its sub-hierarchy, for example:

```
Hierarchy   Price   Type    Region
A   30  I   X
```

which is adding:

```
A   10  I   X
A/B   10  I   X
A/B/C   10  I   X
```

Another case is:

```
Hierarchy   Price   Type    Region
A   10  K   Y
```

In the input date doesn't have record for "Hierarchy" A in "Type" K, but has:

```
A/B/C   10  K   Y
```

Since A/B/C is the sub-hierarchy of A, so

```
A   10  K   Y
```

is added to the output.

```
df.groupby(grp_df['Hierarchy'].str.split('/').str[0], sort=False).sum().reset_index()
```

But it only gave:

```
Hierarchy   Cost          
A   140
```

Comment: HI NexusDreamer! I was wondering if you wanted to use empty values as information (i.e. separate out A/B/Cs from A/B/Nones, if that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You can create the expected dataframe by exploding
With the same idea as your code, you can add missing rows using 'str.split' and `explode`. However, you have to fix the `Hierarchy` column to get the expected dataframe:

```
# Step 1. Add missing rows
funcs = {col: 'first' for col in df.columns} | {'Cost': 'sum', 'Node': 'first'}
nodes = df['Hierarchy'].str.split('/')
out = (df.assign(Node=nodes).explode('Node')
         .groupby(['Node', 'Type', 'Region'], as_index=False)
         .agg(funcs))

# Step 2. Fix the hierarchy
paths = out['Hierarchy'].str.split('/', expand=True)
paths *= paths.eq(out['Node'], axis=0).replace(False, None).bfill(axis=1)
paths = paths.melt(ignore_index=False).dropna().groupby(level=0)['value'].agg('/'.join)
out['Hierarchy'] = paths
```

Output:

```
# Final result
>>> out
   Hierarchy  Cost Type Region Node
0          A    30    I      X    A
1          A    30    I      Y    A
2          A    30    J      X    A
3          A    30    J      Y    A
4          A    10    K      X    A
5          A    10    K      Y    A
6        A/B    20    I      X    B
7        A/B    20    I      Y    B
8        A/B    20    J      X    B
9        A/B    20    J      Y    B
10       A/B    10    K      X    B
11       A/B    10    K      Y    B
12     A/B/C    10    I      X    C
13     A/B/C    10    I      Y    C
14     A/B/C    10    J      X    C
15     A/B/C    10    J      Y    C
16     A/B/C    10    K      X    C
17     A/B/C    10    K      Y    C

# Before fix (before step 2)
>>> out
   Hierarchy  Cost Type Region Node  # <- This column gives the depth of the path
0          A    30    I      X    A
1          A    30    I      Y    A
2          A    30    J      X    A
3          A    30    J      Y    A
4      A/B/C    10    K      X    A  # Should be fixed, depth A
5      A/B/C    10    K      Y    A  # Should be fixed, depth A
6        A/B    20    I      X    B
7        A/B    20    I      Y    B
8        A/B    20    J      X    B
9        A/B    20    J      Y    B
10     A/B/C    10    K      X    B  # Should be fixed, depth B
11     A/B/C    10    K      Y    B  # Should be fixed, depth B
12     A/B/C    10    I      X    C
13     A/B/C    10    I      Y    C
14     A/B/C    10    J      X    C
15     A/B/C    10    J      Y    C
16     A/B/C    10    K      X    C
17     A/B/C    10    K      Y    C
```

**Note**: the code above is probably a bit slow but it should work. You can also use `networkx` to build the graph and use `Cost` column as weight then find all the simple paths from roots to leaves and collect the weight.

Answer (score 0):

you have to split/divide the hierarchy column into letters, somethig like this:

```
b = ''
for i in 'ABC':
    b += i
    df[b] = 0
    df.loc[df[df['Hierarchy'].str.contains(i)].index, b] = b
```

then you can group by the created columns like this:

```
df.groupby(by=['A','AB','ABC','Type','Region']).sum()
```

this code worked for me.